# Getting rid of annoying rectangular highlights in vs code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want to get rid of highlights as shown in the below picture. I find it really annoying.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Without more info it could be one of two things:

setting:  `Editor: Selection Highlight`  disable that or

change its color via:

```
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
  "editor.selectionHighlightBackground": "#f000",
 }
```

The last digit in that hex is opacity.

or they could be **find** matches in which case you will have to do:

```
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
  "editor.findMatchHighlightBackground": "#0000"
}
```

The hexes can also be `"#ff000000"` eight characters - last two being opacity.

Comment: I can confirm disabling editor selection highlight worked for me. Good question and good answer too.